# Why doesn't NULL propagate in boolean expression in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

In SQL, every operation which involves an operand with NULL yields NULL (with the obvious exceptions of IS NULL or IS NOT NULL operators). However, NULL does not propagate with AND or OR operators which may return TRUE or FALSE. For example, the following in MariaDB 10.4 returns NULL and 0 respectively:

```
select 0 & null, 0 and null
```

The difference is that the first is a bitwise AND, the second is a boolean AND. Why NULL does not propagate in boolean operation?

Comment: Using `NULL` in a bitwise expression does not make much sense, because it is not a bit-based value.  What were you expecting here?

Comment: Which database system and version are you running this code in? I know for sure that code won't run on some and just give an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

A NULL value has a whole series of possible meanings. IIRC Chris Date found about 7 different interpretations.

A very common interpretation of NULL is: "I don't know". Another one is: "Not applicable".

So let's try to evaluate a condition with the "I don't know" interpretation of a NULL value.
As an example suppose there are two persons. And you want to compare their age. Person A happens to be 31 years old. In case of the other person, person B, you don't know.

The question if A is as old as B cannot be answered positively. But it can't be denied either. In fact, you don't know. Hence the truth value here is NULL.

If we add the ages of both persons, we run into the same problem. We don't have a clue about the sum of their ages. Again the resulting value is NULL.

This is why you'll have to define how to treat NULL values. A database system cannot know this.

Answer (score 0):

We have `0 and null`. In MariaDB, `0` and `FALSE` are synonymous. So we have `FALSE AND NULL`. But `FALSE AND <anything>` is always `FALSE` - there's no doubt that no matter what value might be substituted here, nothing can make this statement `TRUE` now.

So we short-circuit and return the `FALSE`/`0` result. Similarly, `1 OR NULL` should return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` has the semantics of "unknown" value.  It does not have the semantics of "missing".  This is a nuance.

But, it is "propagated" by `AND` and `OR`, just not as you might expect.  So:

```
true AND NULL   --> NULL, because the value would depend on what NULL is
false AND NULL  --> false, because the first value requires that the result is false
```

In `WHERE` and `WHEN` clauses, `NULL` is treated as "false".  However, in `CHECK` constraints, `NULL` is treated as "true" -- that is, only *explicitly* false values fail the `NULL` constraint.

Otherwise, you are correct that almost all operations with `NULL` return `NULL`.  The `&` operator is a bitwise operator that has nothing to do with boolean values.  It is just another "mathematical" operator, such as `+`, or `*`, so the value is `NULL` when any operand is `NULL`.

One very important exception is the `NULL`-safe comparison operator, `<=>`.